# How to fix the 'Debug Assertion Failed! Expression file_name != nullptr' error?

Tags: c, visual-c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
FILE *source_fp, *content_fp;
int ch;
if(!(source_fp=fopen(argv[1],"wb")))
{
    printf("can't open file\n");
    return 0;
}

for(int i = 2 ; i < argc ; i++)
{
    if(!(content_fp=fopen(argv[i],"r")))
        printf("can't find file%s\n", argv[i]);
    else
    {
        while(ch = fgetc(source_fp))
        {
            fputc(ch,source_fp);
        }
        fclose(content_fp);
    } 
}
fclose(source_fp);
}
```

I get the following error messages when running this program:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: ...ments\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project9\Debug\Project9.exe File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\stdio\fopen.cpp Line: 30

Expression: file_name != nullptr

For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: C and `file_name = nullptr`?  Must be MSVC.  And you're not checking if `argv[1]` is non-null.

Comment: How many command line parameters do you pass,

Comment: Are you passing the right arguments to your program? You don't check if `argc` is at least 2 (i.e. you don't check if `argv[1]` is valid).

Comment: I think that's probably the problem; check whether `argc > 2` and exit if it isn't before you try to open the first file.

Comment: You never check argc to see if it's 2 or greater before trying to use argv[1]... I'm guessing you're not passing command line arguments to your program when you run it.

Comment: What is line 30?

Comment: @nicomp The program doesn't have a line 30. That's line 30 inside Microsoft's header files, or something. MSVC isn't very helpful.

Comment: That's line 30 of the implementation file for `fopen`. You may look at the file name provided.

Answer (score 1):

Your program makes all the necessary checks *everywhere*... except your first `fopen`. If `argc` is `1`, which it is if you just run your program, then the value you pass to `fopen` will be `NULL`, not a pointer to a valid string. (If `argc` is `0`, which is possible, it won't even be `NULL` and will instead cause Undefined Behaviour.)

To fix this, change:

```
if(!(source_fp=fopen(argv[1],"wb")))
{
    printf("can't open file\n");
    return 0;
}
```

to:

```
if (argc < 2 || !(source_fp = fopen(argv[1], "wb")))
{
    printf("can't open file\n");
    return 0;
}
```

---

Just so you know, the error your compiler's giving you is kind of nonsensical. If you *have* to use Windows, use a decent compiler like [Pelles C](https://www.christian-heffner.de/). It'll tell you what the *actual* errors are.

Also, by convention, if something's gone wrong we return something other than `0`; usually `1`.

Comment: Ha! I didn't know `argc` could be zero as well. I thought that it would be `>= 1` always. Guess you learn something new everyday :-)

Comment: Please note that it is not the compiler that is giving the error. It is the run-time. Having an assertion in the debug run-time library is valid. That it then mentions the name of the internally used variable (`file_name`) is also correct. I wonder if your Pelles does any better.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie It gives you a stack trace in debug mode, instead of just saying "there's an error". What's more, the IDE will point right at the problematic line in _your_ program, instead of in the library, since it automatically climbs the stack trace until it gets to something you'd find useful.

Comment: Well, that is exctly what VC does too in the debug mode: see the stack, see the line in error, see the error in your program, if you want to (or just click on the functions on the stack to see from where in your program the function in error was called).

Comment: @Spikatrix It doesn't have to be zero. If `argc == 1` there is still no string in `argv[1]` but a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: @Gerhardh Second sentence of the answer, and the one preceding what Spikatrix was commenting on.